# How to create your own week intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

I have a 49 dates in my data set and I would like to group them by weeks in order `ASC` without using the `WEEK` or `ISO_WEEK` functions.

The output should look like this:

```
+------------+------+
|   dates    | week |
+------------+------+
| 2019-04-05 |    1 |
| 2019-04-06 |    1 |
| 2019-04-07 |    1 |
| 2019-04-08 |    1 |
| 2019-04-09 |    1 |
| 2019-04-10 |    1 |
| 2019-04-11 |    1 |
| 2019-04-12 |    2 |
| 2019-04-13 |    2 |
+------------+------+
```

Is there a better way than using a `case` statement coupled with a `row_number()` such as this:

```
case when rn <= 7 then w1 when rn >7 and <= 14 then w2 ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use arithmetic:

```
(row_number() over (order by dates) + 6) / 7
```

Comment: is it possible to aggregate a column in the same step as the row_number . say I wanted to count(distinct id) by the week formula you used?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . You would need a subquery.